# The behavior when putting Row into ConstrainedBox with Flutter is strange

Tags: flutter, widget, row

When I put a Row in the ConstrainedBox with Flutter, the display is out of the way.
Is this a Flutter bug?

//Does not Stick out Pattern

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
  maxWidth: ScreenUtil.getFullWidth(context) * 0.8),
  child: Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
    width: 300,
    height: 100,
)),
```

//Stick out Pattern

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
  maxWidth: ScreenUtil.getFullWidth(context) * 0.8),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
        width: 300,
        height: 100,
      )
    ])),
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMzTj.png)

Comment: Do you have a photo?

Although I think if you wrap your container in an expanded widget (for the stick out pattern) it wouldn't stick out

Comment: I think so too, but it actually sticks out
I added an image.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an `Expanded` with a `Center` Widget remove the overflow

```
ConstrainedBox(
          constraints:
              BoxConstraints(maxWidth: ScreenUtil.getFullWidth(context) * 0.8),
          child: Row(children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Center(
                    child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
              width: 300,
              height: 100,
            )))
          ]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

do your ConstrainedBox is inside of a ‌scaffold widget?

That is sometimes required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes.
I'm making a reusable widget, which I use inside Scafold.